# querydsl 3.3.0 - using collection.any() with elementcollections in a query with N boolean arguments generates N "exists" sub-queries

Tags: querydsl

I am attempting to query for a specific item in an ElementCollection that matches 2 criteria.  When I write the query in QueryDSL, the query generated by Hibernate includes 2 exists statements with subqueries, each subquery contains 1 of the criterion I specified.
Here is an example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   @Id
   private Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class Project {

   @Id
   private Integer id;
   private boolean canned;

   @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetClass=ProjectMember.class)
   @CollectionTable(name="Project_Person", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="projectId", nullable=false)})
   private Set<ProjectMember> members;
}

@Embeddable
public class ProjectMember {

   private Integer personId;
   private Integer projectId;
   private boolean overworked;
   private boolean underpaid;
}
```

Now if I try to do the following, I will get multiple exists subqueries, each having one criterion I specify:

```
  QProject project = QProject.project;
  QProjectMember members = project.members.any();
  new HibernateQuery(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession())
  .from(project).where(project.canned.eq(true).or(
  members.overworked.eq(true).and(members.underpaid.eq(true)))).list(project);
```

Here is the output query:

```
select project
from Project project
where project.canned = ?1 or exists (select 1
from Project projectd92b4
  inner join projectd92b4.members as project_membersaeb8a
where projectd92b4 = project and project_membersaeb8a.overworked = ?1) and exists (select 1
from Project project4b8ff
  inner join project4b8ff.members as project_membersb6de1
where project4b8ff = project and project_membersb6de1.underpaid = ?1)
```

As you can see, there are 2 exists statements with subqueries each having one of the 2 criteria.  This query will not produce the correct results as I don't want a project where at least 1 of the members is "overworked" and at least 1 member is "underpaid"; I want a project where at least 1 project member is both "overworked" AND "underpaid."  Am I misunderstanding the proper use of "any()" or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Each any() usage is converted into it's own subquery. If you need to combine multiple conditions you will need to write the subquery yourself.

any() isn't a join alternative, but a subquery exists shortcut. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I chose this route because I was having difficulty finding a way to inner join ProjectMember.  Do you have a suggestion for how to write this query?  Thanks.

Comment: @timo-westkämper what would be the alternative to check, that `.all` collection items specified property equals to a specific value?