# Spring Data - QueryDSL InnerJoin predicate

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Lets assume we have the following domain objects (partially complete to reduce code).

```
public class Student {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    List<Assignment> assignments;
}


public class Assignment {

    @ManyToOne
    Student student;

    @OneToOne
    Implementation implementation;
}

public class Implementation {

    @OneToOne
    Assignment assignment;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="implementation")
    List<Assessment> assessments;
}

public class Assessment {

    @ManyToOne
    Implementation implementation;

    String grade;
}
```

So the query I want to perform is `"Select all students whose assignment implementation has been performed (not null) and has not been assessed at all (List<Assessment>#isEmpty()`)

So I'm using `QueryDSL` and try to use the following query just to get Students with non-implemented assignments

```
    public class MyService {

        @Autowired
        private StudentRepository studentRepository;

        public Iterable<Student> foo() {
            return studentRepository.findAll(
                QStudent.student.assignments.any().implementation.isNotNull()
            );
        } 
    }
```

and the above query seems to get ignored.

Then I use the following to get the combination (`implemented exercises and empty assessments`)

```
studentRepository.findAll(
    QStudent.student.assignments.any().implementation.isNotNull() 
      .and(QStudent.student.assignments.any().implementation.assessments.isEmpty())
);
```

Again this makes no differences. Any idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "and the above query seems to get ignored"? Are no students returned or are all returned even if the don't fulfill the predicate?

Comment: All students are returned even though they don't fulfill the predicate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
QAssignment assignment = QAssignment.assignment;
ListSubQuery<Assignment> subQuery = new JPASubQuery().from(assignment)
    .where(assignment.implementation.isNotNull()))
    .and(assignment.implementation.assessments.isEmpty())
    .list(assignment);

studentRepository.findAll(
    QStudent.student.assignments.contains(subQuery)
);
```

I'm not sure why your code is not working, but I guess it's because
`any()` is only a subquery exists shortcut.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453708/2672352